# TextBuffer is locked by an edit operation in VS 2015 HTMLX Editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I am using Visual Studio 2015 update 2.

I am writing extension that uses html editor.

Sometimes I get error saying "Attempted TextBuffer edit while another edit operation is in procces" and that prevents me from writing into the window
How do I know which opperation has the buffer locked?

It happens by some more or less randomly. (At least i can not find any reliable way to reproduce it.)
Just commands that chenge TextBuffer are affected so I can debug freely.

I will gladly provide any aditional info if needed.

I managed to log exception that it trows. Its quite long due to command target chain, but It seems like something prevents writing into projection buffer. (Undo Manager?)

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Attempted TextBuffer edit operation while another edit is in progress. 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Implementation.BaseBuffer.TextBufferBaseEdit..ctor(BaseBuffer baseBuffer) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Projection.Implementation.ProjectionBuffer.CreateEdit(EditOptions options, Nullable`1 reiteratedVersionNumber, Object editTag) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.Implementation.EditorOperations.InsertText(String text, Boolean final, String undoText, Boolean isOverwriteModeEnabled) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.Implementation.EditorOperations.InsertText(String text, Boolean final) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Operations.Implementation.EditorOperations.InsertText(String text) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.InsertChar(IntPtr pvaIn, Boolean provisionalText) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.Undo.UndoManagerCommandFilter.Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VerticalDetail.VerticalContentCommandFilter.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.Find.FindCommandFilter.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.IntellisenseCommandFilter.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.BraceCompletionCommandFilter.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Package.Commands.Html.HtmlTextViewFilter.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Interop.OleToCommandTargetShim.Invoke(Guid group, Int32 id, Object inputArg, Object& outputArg) 
at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Controller.Controller.Invoke(Guid group, Int32 id, Object inputArg, Object& outputArg) 
at Microsoft.Web.Editor.Controller.ViewController.Invoke(Guid group, Int32 id, Object inputArg, Object& outputArg) 
at Microsoft.Html.Editor.Commands.HtmlMainController.Invoke(Guid group, Int32 id, Object inputArg, Object& outputArg) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Html.Interop.CommandTargetToOleShim.Exec(Guid& guidCommandGroup, UInt32 commandID, UInt32 commandExecOpt, IntPtr variantIn, IntPtr variantOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at DotVVM.VS2015Extension.Bases.Commands.BaseCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) in ... 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at DotVVM.VS2015Extension.Bases.Commands.BaseCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) in ... 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at DotVVM.VS2015Extension.Bases.Commands.BaseCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) in ... 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at DotVVM.VS2015Extension.Bases.Commands.BaseCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) in ... 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at DotVVM.VS2015Extension.Bases.Commands.BaseCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) in ...
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at DotVVM.VS2015Extension.Bases.Commands.BaseCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdId, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) in ... 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.InnerExec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.SimpleTextViewWindow.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.SendCommand(Guid cmdGroup, UInt32 cmdID, Object inParam) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.TextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs args) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.<>c.<DispatchTextInputEvents>b__6_0(KeyProcessor p, TextCompositionEventArgs args) 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.<>c__DisplayClass10_1`1.<Dispatch>b__0() 
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)
```

Answer (score -1):

I get the same error.  Close and re-open VS is the only solution I have found that works...

HTH,